# gen_fsm erlang timeout

Tags: erlang, gen-fsm

I have a question on gen_fsm timeout. Let's say you have a set of gen_fsm with two states (in future can be more): `idle` which is the starting state and `working`.

Any 5 seconds the gen_fsm will check a particular parameter and according to it will remain in `idle` or will move to `working`.  Whenever a gen_fsm will move to `working`, it will send a message (using `gen_fsm:send_all_state_event/2`) to all the other gen_fsm: the ones in `idle` should move to `working` while the one in `working` should not care about the incoming message.

Now, the point is that I don't want to have a skew in the states timeout (e.g. what happens if the machine is in `working` for 3 seconds and receives a message? A 5 seconds timeout is no more valid, since I want to preserve a fixed timeout no matter what (this means that a timeout message should be triggered at fixed times).

Here are the salient parts of my solution, which uses `now()` and `time:now_diff/2`. I have a small drift anyhow, but seems fair since talking about fractions of seconds.

Do you think it is valid?

```
{ok, idle, #state{time = now()}, 5000}.

idle(timeout, State) ->
    %% do some operations
    {next_state, idle, State#state{time = now()}, 5000}.

working(timeout, State) ->
    %% do some other actions
    {next_state, working, State#state{time = now()}, 5000}.

handle_event(work, working, #state{time = Time} = State) ->
    Timeout = round(timer:now_diff(now(), Time) / 1000),
    {next_state, working, State, Timeout}.

handle_event(work, StateName, state{time = Time} = State) ->
    Timeout = round(timer:now_diff(now(), Time) / 1000),
    {next_state, working, State, Timeout}.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use either [timer:apply_interval](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/timer.html#apply_interval-4) to call a api function that sends the event to your fsm.

Or you use [timer:send_interval](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/timer.html#send_interval-2) to send a custom message that you can handle in the [handle_info](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/gen_fsm.html#Module%3ahandle_info-3) callback in your gen_fsm.

Comment: In fact i changed the code using in each state gen_fsm:send_event_after(5000, timeout). what do you think of this?

Comment: This has the disadvantages IMHO that you'll get some drifting of the interval again.  To stay on a fixed interval you'll allways need to correct for the current time. The timer:*_interval functions do that correctly for free.